# dataLocationCode field is not available in graph API for multi geo

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Expected or Desired Behavior**

While making API call we should get dataLocationCode for multi geo /non-multi geo (with "" as response non-multi geo and  for multi-geo as per document)

URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null&select=webUrl,siteCollection

**Observed Behavior**

Missing of dataLocationCode in getting all geolocation API
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null&select=webUrl,siteCollection

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": [
        {
            "webUrl": "https://netskopepmskopejpn.sharepoint.com/",
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostname": "netskopepmskopejpn.sharepoint.com",
                "root": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "webUrl": "https://netskopepmskopegbr.sharepoint.com/",
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostname": "netskopepmskopegbr.sharepoint.com",
                "root": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "webUrl": "https://netskopepmskope.sharepoint.com/",
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostname": "netskopepmskope.sharepoint.com",
                "root": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "webUrl": "https://netskopepmskopeind.sharepoint.com/",
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostname": "netskopepmskopeind.sharepoint.com",
                "root": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Response headers corresponding to your request(s):

> Date - Wed, 03 Jul 2019 06:38:47
>   request-id - 566ae7b6-4852-40e3-8485-7daf9c010472
>   SPRequestGuid -1d8dec9e-c071-0000-3f4a-597faa9ba2ef

**Steps to Reproduce**
Make graph API call with graph token

Comment: The graph docs don't say that the call you're making should return a datalocationcode field. Per the official Microsoft graph docs here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0 can you please provide the doc you're referring to that says that it will return the geolocation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/multigeo-discovery for getting sites/location site (all locations)  in multigeo.

Comment: @FrankHuMSFT Any update on this

Comment: Hey Yuvaraj, sorry we're still looking into this. I'm currently engaging with the product group in regards to this and will give you an update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The dataLocationCode will currently be returned by the "beta" endpoint of the API.  We're looking into graduating this to 1.0.  Unfortunately no ETA right now but you can see how it returns the data with the "beta" endpoint today.

Comment: so does that mean that the Beta version of the Microsoft Graph API for SharePoint Sites can enumerate all sites in a multi-geo sharepoint environment?